# Changing post status in one click

Tags: post-status

I want to add custom button "Send for correction" somewhere near the "Publish" button. This custom button must change a post status from "Pending" to my own created status named "On correction".

For a now it is possible to change status with 5 clicks (Edit status -> Dropdown click -> Select On-correction -> Ok -> Save as on correction).

**UPDATE:**

```
add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'send_for_correction_button');
function send_for_correction_button()
{
    //global $post;
    echo '<div id="send-for-correction" class="misc-pub-section"
    style="border-top-style:solid; border-top-width:1px; border-top-color:#EEEEEE; border-bottom-width:0px;">
    <input id="save-post2" class="button button-highlighted"
    type="submit" value="Send for correction" name="save">
        </div>';
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_status');
function save_status($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if ($_POST['save'] == 'Send for correction')
    {
        update_post_meta($post_id, "post_status", 'on-correction');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your custom button in a function and hook it into `post_submitbox_misc_actions` and this will add it right above the publish button.

To change the status use [wp_update_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) in an Ajax function.   Give it a try and post back with your code if you run into any problems.

**UPDATE:**

```
add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'send_for_correction_button');
function send_for_correction_button()
{
    //global $post;
    echo '<div id="send-for-correction" class="misc-pub-section"
    style="border-top-style:solid; border-top-width:1px; border-top-color:#EEEEEE; border-bottom-width:0px;">
    <input id="save-post2" class="button button-highlighted"
    type="submit" value="Send for correction" name="save">
        </div>';
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'my_filter_handler' , '99', 2 );
function my_filter_handler( $data , $postarr )
{
    if ($postarr['save'] == 'Send for correction')
        $data['post_status'] = 'on-correction';

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris for help! I modify your answer with corrected code. I've used filter `wp_insert_post_data`.

Comment: Very nice that you got it to work.  When you click the button does the page refresh?

Comment: Yep. This button is just a copy of a "Save" button and do the same things, it save changes but updates post_status too..